# Using Web Component HTML tags with reflex

Tags: haskell, ghcjs, reflex-dom, ghcjs-dom, ui5-webcomponents

I try to use Web Components in Reflex. Code is as such:

```
buttonUI5 :: DomBuilder t m => T.Text -> m (Event t ())
buttonUI5 t = do
  (e, _) <- element "ui5-button" def $ text t
  return $ domEvent Click e
```

For ui5-button it worked as expected. Other Web Components fire events not defined in Reflex.Dom.Widget.Basic like "liveChange".

How can I translate these into Reflex Events?

Comment: What's 'liveChange'? For Reflex.Dom.Widget.Input.TextInput areas, the textInput_input field is an event which fires on changes to the text area input. Is this what like you are looking for?

Comment: Also, as you probably know, Widget.Dom.Builder.Class.Events lists many types of events covered by reflex. If the events you are looking for are not handled there, im not sure I could help you. But if you add a little more detail to this question you might have better chances.

Comment: I refer to the Web Components to be found here: [https://github.com/SAP/ui5-webcomponents](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-webcomponents) There are several of examples for events of these components that cannot be found in Widget.Dom.Builder.Class.Events. I try to find a way to transform these into Reflex events.

Comment: Markus, thats still a bit general. After a few clicks from that page I can find the API documentation, with a lot of components that have reflex corollaries. For instance TextArea has a "change" event listener and reflex has a change event--which is why i mentioned the reflex TextArea event. I couldn't find any "liveChange". Also, in that API, button only has the "Press" event, which may be why "Click" works but other events don't. Have you tried "Change" with ui5-textarea? But again, without a specific example of something which doesn't work its hard for anybody to supply a solution.

Comment: Trevor, maybe I'm too ambitious. You are right. The events that map are completely sufficient for the PoC I'm doing. I was just wondering if I was interested in some specific event in the WebComponents lib like liveChange in (https://sap.github.io/ui5-webcomponents/playground.html#/components/Input) how I can include them as well.